# Memory leak with pure function and in the listable option of compiled function?

Tags: compile, memory, pure-function

I'm using

`13.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)`

When I repeatedly run the command

```
ClearAll[testset]
testset = {#} & /@ Range[0.1, 1000, 0.0001];
```

I notice that the memory usage of mathematica in task manager keeps increasing, altough I would expect it to stay constant. Is this a bug or am I missing something? I also observed that if I use

```
ClearAll[testset]
testset = {#} & /@ Range[0.1, 1000, 0.0001];// AbsoluteTiming
```

instead, It behaves as expected and the memory usage does not keep increasing with repeated evaluations.

Now, let's try to use this list in the compiled function:

```
test[x_] := {x, x^2, x^3};
testvars = {x};
ctest = With[{varsC = testvars, fun = test[testvars]},
   Compile[{{X, _Complex, 1}},
    Block[varsC, varsC = X; fun],
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
    Parallelization -> True,
    RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]];
```

When I evaulate

```
{#, #^2, #^3} & /@ Range[0.1, 1000, 0.0001];
```

or

```
ctest[#] & /@ testset;
```

then there is no problem with the memory usage. Buuuut, when I run the listable version of the compiled function

```
ctest[testset];
```

It eats a huge chunk of memory again (and the //AbsoluteTiming does not help here either). Note, that I don't even save the result of the computation to a variable. Is this a bug or am I missing something? If it is a bug then is there a workaround to use the listable version of the compiled function without the memory problem?

Comment: Did you try it with $HistoryLength=0?

Comment: Yes, it does solve my first question. Thanks, I missed this. However, the listable version of the compiled function still eats more memory with each subsequent run and the memory is not reclaimed.